# Extending an MUI component gives TS error about "css" property missing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

We have extended SnackbarContent component with our custom one (MySnackbarContent):

```
export interface MySnackbarContentProps extends Omit<SnackbarContentProps, 'variant'> {
  variant?: MyCustomVariant;
  type?: MyCustomType;
  banner?: boolean;
  // ...
}

const MySnackbarContent = forwardRef<HTMLElement, MySnackbarContentProps>(props: MySnackbarContentProps, ref) => {
  const { variant = 'normal', type = 'default', banner = false, ...other } = props;
  const className = ...;

  return <SnackbarContent ref={ref} className={className} {...other} />
}
```

Here is the error that I get when I use the custom SnackbarContent component:

> Property 'css' is missing in type '{ type: "error" | "default" | "success" | undefined; message: string; action: Element; }' but required in type 'Pick<MySnackbarContentProps, "hidden" | "style" | "onSelect" | "slot" | "title" | "className" | "classes" | "innerRef" | "defaultChecked" | "defaultValue" | ... 258 more ... | "actionClickHandler">'.

I do not understand why `css` property is a problem here because we are not using emotion or styled-component (we are using JSS).

Weirdly, everything types are properly checked when I remove `forwardRef`.

A possible way to mitigate this issue is to add `css` property in `MySnackbarContentProps` and set it to something like: `css?: null`. For some reason, `css` property is a required property. Not 100% sure why that is the case here. What am I missing here?

- MUI Version: 4.9.10
- TS Version: 3.6.2
- React: 16.13.0
- React Types: 16.9.34

**EDIT: Explanation for the root cause**

There are three parts at play when trying to understand the root cause.

Firstly, Typescript allows augmenting any type and the result of the augmentation will be merging of properties in different definitions. For example, the code below:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

interface Person {
  age: number;
}
```

will be the same as writing the following:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3AQL4EGiSyIrpRsuQiWRxG1UgFdyAI2isOBAPQAqVUVVpMOZN2jwkpLAHdkCHBmB0MyLDGSysYABbIADlCzvoYYBAxNZAATCBhQCGCAOiCggSF8IOIySho6BhAWJLEJGhAZeShWZC0OEuVOCxA6WixKeJwaBtwAXkTRFMkAchcIABs+rC6AGiIScUkARgAmdlYCKprsep0QAHVgVywpMABBXO1BXTaREk6aHv7BkbmgA)

This augmentation does not need to be in the same module/file; so, any module in the project (including node_modules) can augment any type in another module).

Secondly, Material UI allows passing all DOM properties to many of its components. So, it is essentially extending base `React.DOMAttributes<T>` (e.g Paper extends [`React.DOMAttributes<HTMLDivElement>`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/77a8daeed0e8efa67c6d86f3cc40239dc6eb3d94/packages/material-ui/src/Paper/Paper.d.ts#L5)) in a lot of components.

For me, I was able to find the problem because I knew that `css` is a property of `emotion`, which is used by Storybook; so, I dug deeper to see what emotion does and found the following: https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/blob/31e610f2385d5a3dfd532b31f743e5f6b9fee43b/packages/react/types/index.d.ts#L99

So, emotion is augmenting `React.DOMAttributes<T>` by adding **optional** `css` property to it. If any type extends from this type, they will have access to `css` property. This was enough for me to identify the culprit. The library was exporting a utility that was meant to be used in Storybook (some storybook functions were being imported from those utilities). Removing that component from the output solved the issue. If you are using Storybook, check if the outputted package used any of the Storybook components.

One thing that I did not investigate was why the `css` was a mandatory property even though emotion was passing the prop as optional.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: I found out why this was happening. I was using Storybook for showcasing the components and I was including some storybook related components in the bundle.

Comment: @Gasim if you can provide more details on how you solved that, that would be greatly appreciated. I'm facing the exact same issue

Comment: @HHK I added an explanation for the root cause. If you are using storybook, make sure that Storybook components are not included in your bundle. If you are not using Storybook, you might have some other library using emotion internally and causing this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the follow-up, Gasim !

For me the root issue was also caused by Storybook being bundled with the application, because we're using Storybook files with a `*.stories.tsx` extension.
Typescript loads all `.tsx` files in our setup, which in turn loads the global Emotion prop augment OP mentioned.

I had to add `"exclude": ["**/*.stories.tsx"]` to our `tsconfig.json` to fix it.

Comment: Oh really thanks! This works to me.